# "void" Return type for overloaded operator

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I am currently studying "Object-oriented design choices" by Dingle (2021), a required textbook for my Object-Oriented Design Class. While going through the chapter on "Move Semantics," I encountered an example discussing deep and shallow copying, which struck me as unusual.

The first half of this chapter delves into copy semantics, specifically the Copy Constructor and the Overloaded Assignment Operator.

The example in question, provided in the book and simplified for clarity, is as follows:

```
class goodMM {
private:
    int* m_heapData;
    int m_size;

    void copyData(const goodMM& other) {
        // ...
    }

public:
    goodMM(int size) {
        // ...
    }

    ~goodMM() {
        // ...
    }

    goodMM(const goodMM& other) {
        // ...
    }

    void operator=(const goodMM& other) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The part that sticks out to me is the `operator` definition. I was taught that the `operator` should always return a reference `&` to allow for:

- Chaining assignment `a = b = c`
- Efficiency (avoids copying which can be expensive)

I tried to find something related to this topic on google and the SO search engine, but the results yield the `void*()` operator. Checked the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) as well and they all return a reference of type T `[T&]`.

Is there any specific benefit or advantage to declaring the `operator=` as void in this context, as demonstrated in the example from the book?

Comment: Have you tried to consult the book errata, they might fix the shown code.

Comment: @273K Yeah I kept reading on but nothing changed, goes straight into move semantics. On the other hand it doesn't provide a driver, just the class definition...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I emailed the professor, but it's 23:37 right now so I doubt I'll get a response before tommorow morning.

Comment: "Efficiency (avoids copying which can be expensive)" when the return type is `void` there is also no expensive copy

Comment: its only required for chaining. If you need no chaining, the return type does not matter. Its a surprise, but not *wrong*

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Thank you., I am assuming that would have to be a class invariant? "Does not support chaining"?

Comment: This example will miss another important point long since rectified.  It is the use of a raw pointer `int* m_heapData;` in current C++ you should model ownership explicitly e.g. use `std::unique_ptr<int>`. This force you to make a choice in the assignment opetator (share onwership or take over ownership of the memory). And the default move semantics of unique_ptr will move ownership for you

Comment: no a class invariant is something else. Its properties of instances that hold when you use them. Eg you write a class `My_unsigned` then a class invariant is "is never negative". If you like you can call "does not have a chained assignment" a class invariant, but  I dont see what we would gain from that.

Comment: In order to distinguish between `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` as an *owning* pointer, and `Foo*` raw pointer as a non-owning pointer, I've started using `view_ptr<Foo>` to designate a non-owning pointer.  Why?  Because my project has too much code that has raw pointers that are owning pointers.  My project's new convention makes it easier to migrate away from raw owning pointers.